# HTML element screen location .NET

Tags: html, .net, tags, location, screen

I'd like to get specific html tag's on screen location to perform mouse click on it. I tried this:

```
 browser.PointToScreen(elem.OffsetRectangle.Location).ToString();
```

but i only get element's location inside of web control. Can you help me?

Comment: I tried invokeMember("Click") but i guess site use a security system to check if the left mouse click was really pressed.

Comment: It's a "Follow" button, when u press it u actually follow the person

Comment: it's firing server side

Comment: How can i do that? I only have a class name and innertext of the button where i want to click

Comment: Yes it is, but i don't know the name. I only see this:


<span class="hidden-xs truncate">Follow</span>

Comment: Can you guide me please?